# javascript library works only after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, swiper.js

So I'm using *Swiper.js* in order to swipe orizontally some content in my portfolio.
If i open the page locally, everything works fine (I'm able to swipe, buttons are displayed,..) but if I open it on Netlify (free hosting service) I'm having an issue: buttons are displayed but I cannot swipe.

Refreshing the page, fix the problem.

In the head section i have links to CDN

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
```

and the scripts are located right before the end of the body

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

In the console.log i have this error: *"filed to load resource: the  server responded with a status of 404"*.
Refreshing, again, fix the problem.

Do you guys know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why do you have minified version + unminified version? Pick one or the other

Comment: Hi @Costa, I removed the minified version but the issue still exist

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: @JeremyThille actually, there is an error: "filed to load resource: the  server responded with a status of 404"

Answer (score 0):

That is because the library loads before the page and so it cannot locate elements in the DOM, since they don't exist yet.

Add a `defer` attribute to the script tag or place it at the end of the page.

```
<script defer src="..."></script>
```

Comment: hi Mattia, actually the defer attribute makes things worse: now if i refresh the page, library doesn't work anymore

Comment: yep, this is the error displayed: "filed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"

Comment: oh then the file on the server does not exist. check to see if the url is correct